# How to transfer logs from different VM’s (Digitalocen) to a single Logstash using Filebeat

Tags: logstash

From Last two days i got stuck in this task.Task is there are multiple Ubuntu machines are running on cloud (DigitalOcen), I have to take the logs of those machines and ship those logs to Logstash where complete ELK is configured.

I have configured filebeat in one system and my filebeat.yml is like below:

```
filebeat.prospectors:

type: log
paths:
/var/log/nginx/.log
filebeat.config.modules:
path: ${path.config}/modules.d/.yml
reload.enabled: true
output.logstash:
hosts: ["206.189.129.234:5044"]
```

Logstash:-

And my simple logstash.conf file is like Below

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}

}

output {

  elasticsearch {
hosts => "206.189.129.234:9200"
manage_template => false
index => "nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}

}
```

when i start the logstash it is running successfully but I am not able to see any index in elasticsearch. I had tried multiple ways but no results can anyone help me Out of this.

And Is there any particular process is there for above scenario..

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

First of all can you ping from filebeat host, logstash host and from logstash host elasticsearch host?

Then can you check if ports are open and listening?

If everything works fine, try to put

```
/var/log/nginx/.log
filebeat.config.modules:
path: ${path.config}/modules.d/.yml
reload.enabled: true
output.logstash:
hosts: ["HOSTANAME:5044"]
```

and in your logstash pipeline:

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}

}

    output {

          elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://206.189.129.234:9200" (or https, elastic needs to know which protocol you are using)
        manage_template => false
        index => "nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }

        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply It is  working fine now.Thanks for your help

Comment: Your welcome,  if this solves the issue, you should vote for my comment to be the correct answer of your post, so that other people that are in the same situation can find the answer!